# Documentclass article with header

Tags: article, books, headline, documentclass

so at the moment i am writing a document in the class article. But i want the header you have when you use documentclass "book". I dont use class the "book" though because my document is not so long that i could use the chapter-command that generates those giant headlines.
Is there a way to get the headers from the documentclass "book" or can i use the documentclass book somehow and use the normal \section command for the table of content? Because at the moment it puts an "0" in front of all my sections.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `headings` page style (`duckuments` is only required for the dummy content):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with (duckuments is only required for the dummy content). Because it says file duckuments.sty not found

Comment: @chri11 then your LaTeX installation is too old for `duckuments` (it was published a year ago). You don't need it, just add `\pagestyle{headings}` to your document. Everything `duckuments` does is add a few commands to create some dummy content to a document (in this case `\duckument` is used, which adds section headings and text).

Comment: Thank you, that works fine! In my table of content however it still says: 0.1 .... 0.2 ...

Comment: @chri11 if you use `article`?

Comment: yes, it puts a zero infront of the numbers but not in the section itself

Comment: Well actually now it disappeared and everything is just fine - is there a way to put the numbers of the pages at the bottom again?

Comment: @chri11 this is possible, but to customize the page headers and footers beyond the styles that are provided by the standard classes, it is best to load an additional package that allows easier customization, such as `fancyhdr`. You can search on this site, there are enough examples on how to use it.